# How to disable execution of .htaccess and output it's content

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I'm using Apache2 I need to have an http://url/path/.htaccess url,
The url must contain only .htaccess as final (example: https://mywebsite.com/download/.htaccess) nothing less nothing more
as if it was only a normal file (image.jpg), but the content of .htaccess must be displayed as text.

How do I disable the execution of the directives inside the .htaccess and make it display it's content directly without getting a 403 forbidden? inserting the directive to show it's content directly in the .htaccess is not possible as it needs to be downloaded as is and it must be 'operative',
as the end the .htaccess content must be fully operational.

For example doing a wget inside another webhost to that remote url it should exactly download .htaccess and it's content must be valid so if I were to get it from the requesting server(2nd) that downloaded the file, the directives must execute.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your distribution, so YMMV.

With Ubuntu, the default installation has a file named `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, containing:

```
# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

The first directive ([`AccessFileName`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#accessfilename)) sets the name used for `.htaccess`, in case you need to change it. To avoid the .htaccess files be used and the directives inside applied, rename .htaccess to something else, e.g.

```
AccessFileName no.htaccess
```

```
#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

The second directive [`<FilesMatch>`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#filesmatch) is the relevant here and prevents access to any file starting with `.ht`, i.e. both .htaccess and .htpasswd. To allow the files to be accessed from a browser, just comment or remove these lines.

---

Another approach to your problem, could be to keep everything as it is, and name the downloadable files different, e.g. `htaccess` without a dot. This works with any distribution.